# Displaying contents of String array in Swing component as iterations using Time delay. JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, iteration

I have an array of strings which I'm trying to display (one by one) as a slideshow in a Java Swing component. I am also trying to add a delay time between the iterations.

I attempted to do this by using a JTextArea, with an action listener added to it. Here is the code I have right now:

```
private class myActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // A BUNCH OF TEXT PROCESSING

        //NOTE: myInfo.getContents() returns an ArrayList<myType>.
        Iterator<myType> iterator = myInfo.getContents().iterator();

        int i = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            myTextArea.setText(iterator.next().toString());
            // to add time betweeen iterations i wanted to use the thread
            // delay method.
        }
    }
}
```

My code is not working because JTextArea doesn't have an action listener.

**UPDATE**
NOTE: Many replies stated that I should use an ActionListener for the JTextArea; However, Eclipse is not showing me that JTextArea has a method called addActionListener.

I'm kind of stuck here, **which Java Swing component do you think would be the most suitable in this scenario?**

The text in my array may be long, so a one lined label would not be a good choice.

What other alternatives or approaches do I have?

Thank you very much, any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: by letting it sleep() :)

Comment: [Check this out on stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251625/how-to-create-a-delay-in-swing) for ideas.

Comment: bonCodigo, gotcha for the Thread.sleep(), that was quick. Thanks!

Comment: So did it solve your issue? Can I post it as an answer :) BTW you could implement your *own delay* using `System.currentTimeMillis()` That is also explained in the above link I provided.

Comment: I'm just going to use Thread.Sleep(arg) to delay the iterations of the iterator. MY MOST IMPORTANT QUESTION is finding the appropriate Java SWING Component to display this text. Since it is multiline, and the acitonLIstener is NOT implemented by the JTextArea.

Comment: @theSun Thread.Sleep(arg) is one of top of bad practicies in Java, Thread.Sleep(arg) caused freeze Swing GUI, don't do that

Comment: I'm going to use this to run a few tests, and never again. Just trying to get it done.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your `ActionListener` in combination with a `javax.Swing.Timer`. The `ActionListener` assigned to the `Timer` will be called on regular intervals with the specified delay.

See [the timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information

Comment: what about the MAIN question I had, what should I use instead of an Action Listener, because the JTextArea doesn't support one.

Comment: @theSun the action listener is attached to the timer, the action listener s called by the timer after the delay has expired and the action listener shod be used to update the text area

Comment: If you look at this website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html , you see that JTextArea doesn't support an ActionListener. I'm trying to find the appropriate swing component which would allow me to do this.

Comment: @theSun And if you took time time to read the link the Robin supplied, you would see that you don't need one.

Answer (score 5):

This is basic example is based on the suggestion posted by @Robin

```
public class TestDisplayString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDisplayString();
    }

    public TestDisplayString() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea textArea;
        private List<String> content;
        private Iterator<String> iterator;

        public TestPane() {
            readText();
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            textArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
            iterator = content.iterator();

            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        textArea.setText(iterator.next());
                    } else {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void readText() {
            content = new ArrayList<>(25);
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Text.txt")));
                String text = null;
                while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
                        content.add(text);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is the contents of the "Text.txt" file.

> How to Use Swing Timers
>
> A Swing timer (an instance of javax.swing.Timer) fires one or more
>   action events after a specified delay. Don't confuse Swing timers with
>   the general-purpose timer facility that was added to the java.util
>   package in release 1.3. This page describes only Swing timers.
>
> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than
>   general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all
>   share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task
>   automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. However, you
>   might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the
>   GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.
>
> You can use Swing timers in two ways:
>
> ```
> To perform a task once, after a delay.
> For example, the tool tip manager uses Swing timers to determine when to show a tool tip and when to hide it.
> To perform a task repeatedly.
> For example, you might perform animation or update a component that displays progress toward a goal.
> ```
>
> Swing timers are very easy to use. When you create the timer, you
>   specify an action listener to be notified when the timer "goes off".
>   The actionPerformed method in this listener should contain the code
>   for whatever task you need to be performed. When you create the timer,
>   you also specify the number of milliseconds between timer firings. If
>   you want the timer to go off only once, you can invoke
>   setRepeats(false) on the timer. To start the timer, call its start
>   method. To suspend it, call stop.
>
> Note that the Swing timer's task is performed in the event dispatch
>   thread. This means that the task can safely manipulate components, but
>   it also means that the task should execute quickly. If the task might
>   take a while to execute, then consider using a SwingWorker instead of
>   or in addition to the timer. See Concurrency in Swing for instructions
>   about using the SwingWorker class and information on using Swing
>   components in multi-threaded programs.
>
> Let's look at an example of using a timer to periodically update a
>   component. The TumbleItem applet uses a timer to update its display at
>   regular intervals. (To see this applet running, go to How to Make
>   Applets. This applet begins by creating and starting a timer:
>
> timer = new Timer(speed, this); timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
>   timer.start();
>
> The speed and pause variables represent applet parameters; as
>   configured on the other page, these are 100 and 1900 respectively, so
>   that the first timer event will occur in approximately 1.9 seconds,
>   and recur every 0.1 seconds. By specifying this as the second argument
>   to the Timer constructor, TumbleItem specifies that it is the action
>   listener for timer events.
>
> After starting the timer, TumbleItem begins loading a series of images
>   in a background thread. Meanwhile, the timer events begin to occur,
>   causing the actionPerformed method to execute:
>
> public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>       //If still loading, can't animate.
>       if (!worker.isDone()) {
>           return;
>       }
>
> ```
> loopslot++;
>
> if (loopslot >= nimgs) {
>     loopslot = 0;
>     off += offset;
>
>     if (off < 0) {
>         off = width - maxWidth;
>     } else if (off + maxWidth > width) {
>         off = 0;
>     }
> }
>
> animator.repaint();
>
> if (loopslot == nimgs - 1) {
>     timer.restart();
> } }
> ```
>
> Until the images are loaded, worker.isDone returns false, so timer
>   events are effectively ignored. The first part of the event handling
>   code simply sets values that are employed in the animation control's
>   paintComponent method: loopslot (the index of the next graphic in the
>   animation) and off (the horizontal offset of the next graphic).
>
> Eventually, loopslot will reach the end of the image array and start
>   over. When this happens, the code at the end of actionPerformed
>   restarts the timer. Doing this causes a short delay before the
>   animation sequence begins again.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your example. I don't understand why you're using the public void run() inside TextDisplayString(). I don't understand the readText method either.

Comment: All interactions with any AWT/Swing component MUST be done within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. The the thread that launches your application is not the same as the that used by EDT. Read [this](http://bitguru.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/will-the-real-swing-single-threading-rule-please-stand-up/). As for the `readText` method, this is basic [IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). The big difference is the text file I was reading existing within the context of the application and not on the file system

Comment: TY MadProgrammer, got it working! Question: Would I have to deal with concurrency issues if I was displaying three different contents in three different Jtextareas?

Comment: So long as your updating the text areas within the context of the EDT, no. The javax.swing.Tiner will always call actionPerformed within the EDT

Comment: I'd also appreciate it if you could mark Robins question as correct. As it was his suggestion, I just filled it out

Comment: what would I have to do, if I wanted to repeat the iterations again? 

So, if (iter.hasNext) {} else { what do I do, to rerun the iterations again?}

Comment: Y have to recreate the iterator