# Issue adding statements to JTextArea with delays in between

Tags: java

In the code below I am running my method which adds text to a JTextArea, then i wait 4 seconds and add more text. However it simply waits four seconds then puts all the text down at once. How can I make it so it adds the first text, waits then adds the second block of text?

```
   public static void configuresettings() {

    GUI.add("To Begin, Go to www.opionsxo.com");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GUI.add("Welcome to Configure Settings!");



}
```

I figured it out, if anyone is interested in how. Then view the code below...

```
           public static void configuresettings() {

    GUI.add("To Begin, Go to www.opionsxo.com");

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            GUI.add("Welcome to Configure Settings!");
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer( 4000, actionListener );

        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();






}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `Thread.sleep` with `swing`, or it will block your application. For instance, if you resize your window or move a window in front of your application, it won't repaint as needed, because you stopped it. Instead, you should be using `Swing Timers`.

<del>Your problem is probably because you should `revalidate()` your `JTextArea` before `sleep` or something, but as said, you should change the implementation of it.</del>

Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: `revalidate` deals with the layout manager API and if the OP blocks the EDT, it won't have any effect until the method returns...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread that might cause it to stop, like calling `Thread.sleep`.

Instead, trying using a `javax.swing.Timer` or `SwingWorker`

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

For more details

For example:

- [java for-loop in GUI TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332135/java-for-loop-in-gui-textarea/18332315#18332315)
- [Displaying contents of String array in Swing component as iterations using Time delay. JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548982/displaying-contents-of-string-array-in-swing-component-as-iterations-using-time/13549338#13549338)
- [I cant run JTextArea multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957845/java-i-cant-run-jtextarea-multiple-times/15957975#15957975)

Comment: I'll try implementing a timer